# Mounting USB in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I know there are a few of these posts but please bear with me because I have still not been able to mount USB flash drives in my Windows 10 guest OS.

- My host system is Ubuntu 16.04
- My VirtualBox version is 5.0.36
- I have installed the Oracle extensions for VirtualBox
- I have also installed the guest addtions
- My guest OS is Windows 10
- I have added my user to the vboxusers groups
  When I right click at the bottom of the VB interface and select a USB device to mount I hear the Widows 'alert' sound that indicates new hardware detected, but the drive is never mounted, or installed. Doesn't show up in the disk manager either. I thought it might be an issue with that VM so I tried on several others (all Windows) and I got the same result.

Comment: I use KVM rather than virtualbox, but you may try updating your program to the current version, which is virtualbox 5.1.22

Comment: Does it happen with different USB drives?

Comment: Hi, Katu. Yes, it happens with various USB drives.